# How to perform Animal Detection using Kinect / RGB-Depth camera?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, kinect, detection

Currently I'm trying to develop a program which can skeleton track 
From the research I've been doing, I found out that the best way to tackle this problem is by using an RGB-Depth Camera such as Kinect.

**Challenge** : MS Kinect does not support skeleton tracking therefore  I need to build a custom skeleton tracking

**First Problem** :  How  to Detect with a RGB-Depth camera?

**What I found** : Use a machine learning algorithm

**Question**: Is machine learning the only option to detect ? do I need the depth information for detection?

Comment: What's your target? Detect "any" animal or detect a special one (like a dog)? Do you want to estimate pose (e.g. leg positions)?

Comment: Maybe you can find literature about kinect human detection and adapt that for dogs? Human faking a dog pose shouldnt be a problem unless you expect big dogs. But this is only a guess since Ive got no experience in that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the depth channel for the purpose of segmentation of the target silhouette, and then extract descriptive features and classify with them.

I'm not sure if what you need is to classify a target as human or animal, or whether you need to find what type of animal.  If you need the former, features such as aspect ratio are very simple and good separators.  If you need to classify which animal, it depends on the list of classes.  Some cases are easier and some are harder.